# Writing into a document using Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var devices = $(".menu-item-custom").map(function() {
            return this.id.substr(10);
        }).toArray();

        $.each(devices, function() {

            $("#menu-item-settings-"+this+" .description").eq(3).after("<p class='description description-thin'><label for 'translated_title_"+this+"_ar'>عربي<br><input type= 'text' class='widefat edit-menu-item-title' name='translated_title_"+this+"_ar value='"+$(document).write('ssss')+"' '></label></p>");

        });

});
```

Using this code I'm trying to write into the value attribute, but this error appears:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'write'
```

Comment: Oh... That's a real mess here :)

Comment: I suggest to learn something about [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) / [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM) first, before getting involved with  [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Comment: And maybe some general programming as well.

Comment: `$(document)` returns a jQuery object.

Comment: You could just use `...value='ssss' >...`. and I think that error is the least of your problems.

Comment: `this` is not what you probably think it is there... `$.each` takes the `index` and `value` as parameters...

Comment: @elclanrs `this` in a `jQuery.each(<array>, <fn>)` refers to the array element, which is a string in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that there's no `write` function on `$(document)` (which is not the same as `document`).

But perhaps more to the point, you're creating a string to pass to `.after`. That's no place to be writing to the document. The following will suffice, for creating a string:

```
value='" + 'ssss' + "'
```

(assuming `'ssss'` will in production code be a variable, otherwise there is of course no need for concatenation at all)

Answer (score 2):

Either use `document.write` (native browser implementation)

or jQuery's `$('#element').html('<p>....')`

Comment: Either suggested method will not cause the OPs code to produce something senseful.

Comment: It explains his error, due to `$(document).write('ssss')` which is incorrect; It's trying to use a `.write()` method on a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `write` in jQuery objects.

Use `$("#element").append` instead of `document.write`. (You can append `textnodes`)